# How can I get the same drawerLayout on multiple types of activities without using fragments?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I want to have the same drawerlayout for multiple types of activities.

This works, but how would I be able to use this with a different type of Activity? A FragmentActivity for example.

My base activity:

```
public class BaseDrawerActivity extends Activity {
    protected DrawerLayout _drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        ....stuff with drawerlayout

   }
}
```

And then I extend the class in my stat activity:

```
public class StartActivity extends BaseDrawerActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater startInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View contentView = startInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_start, null, false);
        _drawerLayout.addView(contentView);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't 'want' to use fragments if you're starting an app from scratch. That's they way to go about when using navigation drawer.

Comment: Just, Fyi : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: I would just like to keep using activities if thats possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending from different classes not allowed in Java. So in that case you'll need to extend it from FragmentActivity.

Comment: It's strongly recommended to avoid duplication of code. In that case FragmentActivity is already extended from Activity so you may not extend additionally from Activity. But in case if you wanna use other types (e.g. ActionBarActivity, MapActivity etc) you will maybe have code duplicate problems.